# Creating a content hub and client application using Piranha CMS

Tags: piranha-cms

First off, I need to mention that I'm not sure if what I'm trying to achieve is even supported by Piranha CMS (that's partly what I'm trying to determine here). They mention the ability to create a standalone content hub on their website, but my assumptions of what is possible with that model might be incorrect. What I've already done is created an ASP.NET MVC application that is hosting Piranha CMS and I've published it to Azure websites for testing purposes--that part works as expected. The content management interface is the only user facing piece here--it is meant only to serve as the content hub for the client application (just the one for now as this is just proof of concept work).

I am now trying to build a client ASP.NET MVC application that pulls content from the hub. This is where I'm thinking that my assumptions may have been wrong. I was thinking that I'd be able to install the Piranha CMS nuget package(s) on the client as well, and I'd be able to configure the framework to get content from the hub in the same way that it would if the content were hosted on the client site. I realize that I could get the content from the hub using Piranha's REST api, but what I want to do is to be able to use the more friendly entity model based api for this.

So my question is whether it is possible (within reason) to setup Piranha CMS in the way that I've described. If it is, how exactly do I configure the client such that it is aware of the location of the content hub?

Comment: Have you been able to get your content HUB running? If so, are you using the REST API to access the content from your MVC client? I'm trying to setup the same and it appears that the latest nuget packages from Piranha have moved some objects around and I only get generic errors now when making REST calls.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no .net client api consuming the rest services as the simplest scenario would be to deploy .net applications together with the server. In the setups I've done native apps & html5 knockout/angular applications have used the rest api's for getting json data. You should however be able to white such a module, performing the HTTP calls and the deserializing the json without any problems.

Regards

Håkan